# Add a null caracter to a tuple in regex

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, tuples, pcre

I have this pattern `\w+=([\w\s]+.*?)[,\]]`

saved at [https://regex101.com/r/ui3UHD/1][LINK] and want to capture also the NULL caracter to put in a tuple.
Right now I have for this string

```
id=9, district=, name=OMG LTD
```

the tuple=('9','OMG LTD'), but i need to have ('9','','OMG LTD)
I tried to put \0, \x00 but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
\w+=([\w\s]*.*?)[,\]]
```

Just modified your `[\w\s]+` to `[\w\s]*` so that it also considers null.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ui3UHD/2)